# Perl - can't strip blank lines

Tags: regex, perl

Let's say, I have a file like this (it's not the actual content but the hexdump):

```
0000000  \r  \n  \r  \n   T   h   i   s       i   s       a       f   i
0000010   l   e  \r  \n                              \r  \n   H   e   r
0000020   e   '   s       s   o   m   e       t   e   x   t  \r  \n
000002f
```

If I run the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp;
$_ = read_file("file.txt");

s/^\s*$//mg;
print;
```

The output produced is:

```
0000000  \n   T   h   i   s       i   s       a       f   i   l   e  \r
0000010  \n  \n   H   e   r   e   '   s       s   o   m   e       t   e
0000020   x   t  \r  \n
```

Apparently, the blank lines aren't stripped.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: @knittl Why do you want to overwrite the file content in `$_` with the return value of the substitution? And why on earth did someone upvote that comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In regexes, the `$` assertion can be a bit confusing. According to the docs, it “Match[es] the end of the line (or before newline at the end)”. So it behaves roughly like

```
(?=\n\z)|\z
```

With the `/m` modifier, this changes to

```
(?=\n)|\z
```

This means that the `\n` is not included in the matched substring. You want:

```
s/^\s*\n//mg;
```

Now there remain some points in your code that should be addressed. Mainly, it makes little sense to read in the whole file at once, and run a regex over it. Rather, I'd do:

```
use strict; use warnings; use autodie;

open my $fh, "<", "file.txt";
while (<$fh>) {
  print if /\S/; # print if this line contains at least one non-space character
                 # this elegantly skips whitespace-only lines.
}
```

This assumes that line endings consist entirely of whitespace characters and end with `\n`. This holds for both `\r\n` and `\n` line endings. Else, assign custom line endings like

```
local $/ = local $\ = "\r\n"; # input and output line endings
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;  # remove line endings
  print if /\S/; # print adds the line ending again.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't successful with the multiline match myself, so i split up the content to lines again:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Slurp;

my $content = read_file("test.txt"); # You should'nt set $_ explicitely

foreach (split(/\r\n/,$content)){
    if ($_ =~ /\S/){
        print $_ . "\n";
    }
}
```