# Remove extra empty lines between curly brackets

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to have a perl expression to run from command line to remove the extra line between the curly brackets in this case:

```
  // some code
  }
       <-- empty line to remove
}
// more code
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl - can't strip blank lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102670/perl-cant-strip-blank-lines)

Comment: It seems not duplicated, specially because the user is asking for a solution in perl to run from command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want it to do it when the second curly brace is at the beginning of the line:

```
perl -0777 -pi -we's/}\n\n}/}\n}/g' filename
```

If even if it is indented:

```
perl -0777 -pi -we's/}\n(\n[^\S\n]*(?=}))/}$1/g' filename
```

If there might be extra whitespace on the "empty" line or just after the first curly brace:

```
perl -0777 -pi -we's/(}[^\S\n]*\n)[^\S\n]*\n([^\S\n]*(?=}))/$1$2/g' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to replace `(?<=})\s*\n(?:\s*\n)+(\s*})` with `\n$1`. Unfortunately I don't know perl, so I don't mind if someone steals this pattern to write a complete answer.